# Design approach for quiz application with different types of questions and response types

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to implement this functionality along with the ability of a user to select if the question is a multiple choice question with options, a short answer question stem with an answer field, and an image video question where the stem can be an image with fields to respond.

So far:

```
class Question(models.Model):

    QUESTION_TYPE_CHOICES = [
        ('MCQ', 'MultipleChoiceQuestion'),
        ('SAQ', 'ShortAnswerQuestion'),
        ('IVQ', 'ImageVideoQuestion'),
    ]
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    paper = models.ForeignKey(Paper, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=QUESTION_TYPE_CHOICES, null=True) # MultipleChoiceQuestion, ShortAnswerQuestion, EssayQuestion, ImageVideoQuestion
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class MultipleChoiceQuestion(Question):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    paper = models.ForeignKey(Paper, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    # multiple_choice_question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    multiple_choice_option_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class MultipleChoiceOption(models.Model):
    multiple_choice_question = models.ForeignKey(MultipleChoiceQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    multiple_choice_option_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.multiple_choice_option_text

# applies to short answer questions and essays
class ShortAnswerQuestion(Question):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    paper = models.ForeignKey(Paper, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    # short_answer_question_text = models.TextField() # Text of the question
    answer_text = models.TextField() # Answer to the question
    discussion = models.TextField(blank=True) # Discussion or additional information about the question (optional)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

# applies to OSCEs, POTS or other question with an image, or a video within the stem
class ImageVideoQuestion(Question):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    paper = models.ForeignKey(Paper, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    # image_video_question_text = models.TextField() # Text of the question
    answer_text = models.TextField() # Answer to the question
    discussion = models.TextField(blank=True) # Discussion or additional information about the question (optional)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

The three types of questions are inheriting the base Question class that has the field for a contributor to enter the stem of the question.
What would be the best way to approach this?

When a contributor wants to add a question, they should be able to pick which type of question it is and the corresponding fields automatically appear. For instance, picking a MCQ should result in them seeing option fields where they can add them and highlight which option is correct before saving. If they pick SAQ, they are shown an answer field to insert the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I must mention that it is a sample code that should work for you but you have to update it based on your project to make it work smoothly, I want to show you the procedure.

First, you have to create ModelForm for each question:

```py
from django import forms
from .models import MultipleChoiceQuestion, ShortAnswerQuestion, ImageVideoQuestion

class MultipleChoiceQuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MultipleChoiceQuestion
        fields = ['question_text', 'multiple_choice_option_text']

class ShortAnswerQuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ShortAnswerQuestion
        fields = ['question_text', 'answer_text', 'discussion']

class ImageVideoQuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageVideoQuestion
        fields = ['question_text', 'answer_text', 'discussion']
```

Then create a form that user selects the question type and you show that form to the user:

```py
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    QUESTION_TYPE_CHOICES = [
        ('MCQ', 'Multiple Choice'),
        ('SAQ', 'Short Answer'),
        ('IVQ', 'Image/Video'),
    ]

    question_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=QUESTION_TYPE_CHOICES)
    question_form = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['question_type'].widget.attrs.update({'onchange': 'show_question_form();'})

        self.forms = {
            'MCQ': MultipleChoiceQuestionForm(prefix='mcq'),
            'SAQ': ShortAnswerQuestionForm(prefix='saq'),
            'IVQ': ImageVideoQuestionForm(prefix='ivq'),
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(QuestionForm, self).clean()
        question_type = cleaned_data.get('question_type')

        if question_type not in self.forms.keys():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid question type')

        return cleaned_data
```

You have to add a JS script in your code to let user switch between forms:

```html
<!-- Your HTML template -->
<script>
    function show_question_form() {
        var questionType = document.getElementById('id_question_type').value;
        var formDivs = ['id_question_form_mcq', 'id_question_form_saq', 'id_question_form_ivq'];

        for (var i = 0; i < formDivs.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById(formDivs[i]).style.display = 'none';
        }

        if (questionType) {
            document.getElementById('id_question_form_' + questionType.toLowerCase()).style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
</script>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <div id="id_question_form_mcq" style="display:none;">
        {{ form.forms.MCQ.as_p }}
    </div>
    <div id="id_question_form_saq" style="display:none;">
        {{ form.forms.SAQ.as_p }}
    </div>
    <div id="id_question_form_ivq" style="display:none;">
        {{ form.forms.IVQ.as_p }}
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Then you can handle the form submission like this in your view:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def add_question(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            question_type = form.cleaned_data['question_type']
            if question_type == 'MCQ':
                question_form = form.forms['MCQ']
            elif question_type == 'SAQ':
                question_form = form.forms['SAQ']
            elif question_type == 'IVQ':
                question_form = form.forms['IVQ']

            if question_form.is_valid():
                # Save the question and its corresponding type-specific fields
                question = form.save(commit=False)
                question.save()

                specific_question = question_form.save(commit=False)
                specific_question.question = question
                specific_question.save()

                return render(request, 'success.html')
    else:
        form = QuestionForm()

    return render(request, 'add_question.html', {'form': form})
```